# How to compare current time with time from database?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a field `time` in my MySQL database with the value: `08:05:00`.

I need to compare this value with the current time.
I attempted to do this:

```
now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev'))
current_minute = now.minute
current_hour = now.hour

parse_time = split('08:05:00')

if int(current_hour) == parse_time[0] and (int(parse_time[1]) == int(current_minute)):
    print "Current hour and minute are the same with value in db"
```

I am not sure in this. Is it correct? I mean this expression:

```
int(current_hour) == parse_time[0]
```

Comment: What is that makes you ask the question? Is the code not behaving as you'd expect? What are you getting as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `int()` on the wrong variables. `current_minute` and `current_hour` are already integers, while `parse_time` contains strings, which need to be converted to integers. So it should be:

```
if current_hour = int(parse_time[0]) and current_minute = int(parse_time[1]):
```

However, when you're doing your database query, you could use

```
SELECT HOUR(time) AS hour, MINUTE(time) AS minute, ...
```

to return these as integers, then you don't need to split it or convert them in Python.

Comment: `current_hour` is `08`: or `8`?

Comment: `now` contains numbers, not strings.

Comment: Are you sure about `current_hour` as `08` but not `8` for `now.hour`?

Comment: I'm sure that `now.hour` contains an integer, not a string.

Comment: It says it's in `range(24)`. That's a list of numbers from `0` to `23`.